# stristr with special chars æøåü etc

Tags: php

Why is this not a match?

http://www.tehplayground.com/#UREUvT4yr

```
$str = 'Bülow';

if(stristr($str, 'BÜLOW')){
    echo 'match';
}
else{
    echo 'no match';
}
```

## update

same problem with `strtolower`

```
echo strtolower('BÜLOW'); // returns: bÜlow
```

Comment: Because `Ü` is not technically the uppercase version of `ü`. Check out the `mb_` functions. There might be a `stristr` in there.

Comment: Worked fine for me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if the links works for you then there must be something wrong with my internet provider.. It returns `no match` ;)

Comment: it's not the link, it's that I've tested what you posted on my own machine that worked. could be an encoding issue on the file/server

Comment: @Rudie there are no unicde chars in the string and `mb_*` is for unicode char strings

Comment: `mb_*` functions are for `multibyte` char strings, not specifically `unicode` char strings

Comment: sorry.. I meant multibyte.. but the string doesn't contain multibyte chars

Comment: So what charset are `ü` and `Ü`?

Comment: Quote form the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) `Note that 'alphabetic' is determined by the current locale. This means that e.g. in the default "C" locale, characters such as umlaut-A (Ä) will not be converted.`

Comment: sorry.. you where right :) `mb_*` is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`mb_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stristr.php) functions (`mb_stristr`) because they can operate on multi byte characters. PHP's strings are really byte arrays. They don't know what a character is.